# Mysql TRIM() not working

Tags: mysql, mariadb, trim

I am not sure why but `TRIM()` or `RTRIM()` not working for me.

```
SELECT TRIM('YV4.3x2.8SA-2 ');
```

is returning `'YV4.3x2.8SA-2 '`.

I can not remove all the spaces as the string may contain space in between.

Comment: Sounds strange, this is working for me. What does `SELECT TRIM('YV4.3x2.8SA-2 '), LENGTH('YV4.3x2.8SA-2 '), LENGTH(TRIM('YV4.3x2.8SA-2 '));` yield for you?

Comment: [Works for me](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/26832)...

Comment: When I copied it from the comment it worked. But when it is coming from database it is not working. Must be some hidden characters.

Comment: @lc. Please check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/26834

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, [that last character is `0xC2A0`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/26837), not `0x20` (space). That is UTF-8 encoding for Unicode code point U+00A0, also known as a [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space).

---

To remove these using `TRIM()`, pass `convert(0xC2A0 using utf8mb4)` for `remstr`:

```
select TRIM(convert(0xC2A0 using utf8mb4) FROM 'YV4.3x2.8SA-2 ');
```

([SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/26839))

---

If you potentially have a mix of these characters and spaces, the easiest method to remove both would be to first replace the NBSP's with regular spaces, then pass the result through `TRIM()`:

```
select TRIM(REPLACE('YV4.3x2.8SA-2 ', convert(0xC2A0 using utf8mb4), ' '));
```

([SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/26842), with a mix of spaces thrown in)

Answer (score 0):

Try this `SELECT TRIM(BOTH ' ' FROM 'YV4.3x2.8SA-2 ');`